# Uncaught TypeError: #<HTMLSpanElement> is not a function at Array.find

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I'm trying to get some code to work, and I'm getting a really interesting error. It's not coming directly from my code, it's coming from Array.prototype.find.

Here's the full error.

```js
Uncaught TypeError: #<HTMLSpanElement> is not a function
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:5:16
(anonymous) @ VM28595:5
```

And this is my code.

```js
var toappend = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnail-2d-container")
var withThumb = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[thumbnail-type="gameIcon"]'))

for(i=0; i < toappend.length; i++) {
  if(withThumb.find(toappend[i])) {
    let newdiv = document.createElement("DIV")
    toappend[i].appendChild(newdiv)
    newdiv.classList.add("shadowcontainer")
  }
}
```

Comment: The function you want to use is `includes()`, not `find()`.

Comment: The argument to `find()` is a function that tests whether an array element should be returned.

Comment: You don't need the loop, you can combine the selectors with `document.querySelectorAll('.thumbnail-2d-container[thumbnail-type="gameIcon"]')`

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks for the help.

Comment: That fixed it! I'm used to other languages where find returns a bool value, like Includes.

Comment: It doesn't return a boolean, it returns the object that was found. But the important difference is that it doesn't look for a specific value, it looks for a value for which the function returns true.

Comment: `find` takes function predicate. Without the context it is hard to know what you are trying to do. Please can you create a fiddle or stackblitz